# Can I point my project to a locally stored glut.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, glut

I have a c++ opengl project that uses glut. It runs fine in my computer, but I need to be able to run it on a lab computer. When I try to do this, it tells me the glut.dll is not installed, but I do not have the privileges to put the file in the proper system folder on the computer. Is there anyway I can store the file with my game, and point to it in my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add required dlls to your project and set property to copy local.

Executable looks for dlls in folders listed in `$PATH` and in the folder with `exe` file.

Comment: Thanks! I just put the dll in int the same directory as the .exe like you mentioned, did not think it was that simple.

Comment: @ColeCanning I'm glad I helped. If it's what were you looking for, you could also accept the answer

Comment: yes I tried earlier, but it made me wait a half an hour. Thanks again.